# Prevent debian from messing up grub configuration

Tags: grub

I have a tripleboot of two debian 7.0 installs (one for development, one for gaming). I also have a full-disk-encrypted install of Kali Linux 2.0. When I did `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` on the game machine, it updated grub and (I think) ran `update-grub`. The entries for Kali Linux and the dev-machine have disappeared from the grub screen. I know I can solve this by chrooting into the Kali install and running `update-grub`, but I don't want to chroot every time I update grub. I want to prevent the two Debian machines from updating grub. If it is possible, I would like to still be able to update the kernels on the Debian machines, but this is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to add the appropriate files to `/etc/grub.d` on all your systems so that it's safe to run `update-grub` anywhere. I imagine that's documented but I haven't looked.

Nevertheless, assuming you'll manage your grub menus manually, you can disable the automatic `update-grub` on kernel installations (and removals) by removing `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub` and `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub`, or better yet, editing them to add `exit 0` just after `#! /bin/sh`, so they start as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh
exit 0
set -e
```

That way it will be easier to undo the change if necessary.

Comment: Will this disable updating grub entirely or only on kernel update?

Comment: Only on kernel updates.

Comment: So when I update grub on the debian machines, it will still update?

Comment: Can you show me how to add the files in `/etc/grub.d/`?

Comment: When grub is upgraded, it will re-generate the menu and run `update-grub`, yes. Adding the files in `/etc/grub.d` will be highly dependent on your setup; you can either just hack something together based on `40_custom` or try to adapt the various `10_linux` scripts to do the right thing (but that might end up being rather complicated).

Comment: Can I alias `update-grub` to `/bin/true` ?

Comment: Yes, that would work; divert `update-grub` first with `dpkg-divert --divert /usr/sbin/update-grub.real --rename /usr/sbin/update-grub`, then `ln -s /bin/true /usr/sbin/update-grub`.